# Get cell text from DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have a DetailsView control that is not attached to a datasource, but is populated by a storedprocedure. Also, I am not defining any fields in the markup. What I'm having a problem with is grabbing cell text during the ItemUpdating event. For example, I want to grab the text from cell 1 from each of five rows and store them to a variable, but the text of the variable comes back null every time. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my markup and then the codebehind:

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="goalsDetailsView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                            CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="GoalID,TaskSetID" Height="50px" 
                            onitemcreated="goalsDetailsView_ItemCreated" 
                            onmodechanging="goalsDetailsView_ModeChanging" 
                            OnPageIndexChanging="goalsDetailsView_PageIndexChanging" Width="100%" 
                            onitemdeleting="goalsDetailsView_ItemDeleting" 
                            onitemupdating="goalsDetailsView_ItemUpdating">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />                                             
                            </Fields>

                        </asp:DetailsView>



protected void goalsDetailsView_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Accessing Edited values from the Details View            

        //grab the goalid and create a string guid
        string strgoalid = goalsDetailsView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text; //GoalID
        Guid goalid = new Guid(strgoalid);

        //grab the tasksetid and create a string guid
        string strtasksetid = goalsDetailsView.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text; //TaskSetID
        Guid tasksetid = new Guid(strtasksetid);

        //grab goal text
        //string goal = ((TextBox)GoalsGridView.Rows[3].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text; //Company
        string goal = goalsDetailsView.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text; 

        //grab task text            
        string Task1 = goalsDetailsView.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text; //Task 1
        string Task2 = goalsDetailsView.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text; //Task 2
        string Task3 = goalsDetailsView.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text; //Task 3
        string Task4 = goalsDetailsView.Rows[6].Cells[1].Text; //Task 4
        string Task5 = goalsDetailsView.Rows[7].Cells[1].Text; //Task 5



        UpdateOrAddNewRecord(goalid, tasksetid, Task1, Task2, Task3, Task4, Task5, goal, true); // call update method            
        BindDetailsView(); // Rebind GridView to reflect changes made
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this in another project of mine; you want to get it from the DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs argument - this contains all the new values being submitted by the form

```
string task1 = e.NewValue[3]; // etc
```

you may want to cast the value as a string `System.Convert.ToString(e.NewValue[3]);` Try not to use CStr()!

Hope this helps.